# Btrfs: New device added to RAID1 not being used

Tags: btrfs, raid1

### The problem

I added a new drive to my RAID1 array, and while it's listed as part of the array, it is not being written to for new data (in spite of being the largest drive and empty). Also, `sudo btrfs fi usage` does show it as part of the array, but is not listed under the `Data,RAID1` nor `Metadata,RAID1` sections (see output below).

Although every guide I could find shows that I added a new device to an existing RAID1 array correctly, it's not.

### Prologue

Those familiar with RAID but not necessary Btrfs' implementation of it, might understandably assume that you can't do RAID1 with an odd number of disks. But Btrfs isn't actually traditional "RAID1", it's something else. It's arguably more flexible, and takes any number of any sized disks >1, makes sure that each chunk is written to any two different disks (usually starting with the ones with most free space), and it's (supposedly) good. It explicitly supports using an odd number of disks. [Here](https://serverfault.com/a/673359/431453) is an example question about that.

### Steps

First, I started with a functioning, recently balanced 4-disk Btrfs RAID1 array. (With 1x4tb, 2x8tb, and 1x10tb drives.) All four disks are part of the data and metadata RAID1 array (see output below).

Then I added a new 10tb disk, via:

```
sudo btrfs device add -f /dev/sdj /mnt/btrfs/ba07
sudo btrfs balance start /mnt/btrfs/ba07  ### As later noted, I also ran this with RAID1 conversion filters.
```

After that, here's the output from `sudo btrfs fi usage /mnt/btrfs/ba07` that seems to indicate that it isn't actually part of the array:

```
Overall:
    Device size:                  36.38TiB
    Device allocated:             17.19TiB
    Device unallocated:           19.19TiB
    Device missing:                  0.00B
    Used:                         16.73TiB
    Free (estimated):              9.82TiB      (min: 9.82TiB)
    Data ratio:                       2.00
    Metadata ratio:                   2.00
    Global reserve:              512.00MiB      (used: 96.53MiB)

Data,RAID1: Size:8.58TiB, Used:8.35TiB
   /dev/sdf        5.68TiB
   /dev/sdg        5.53TiB
   /dev/sdh        3.57TiB
   /dev/sdi        2.38TiB

Metadata,RAID1: Size:18.00GiB, Used:14.21GiB
   /dev/sdf        8.00GiB
   /dev/sdg       17.00GiB
   /dev/sdh        4.00GiB
   /dev/sdi        7.00GiB

System,RAID1: Size:32.00MiB, Used:1.47MiB
   /dev/sdh       32.00MiB
   /dev/sdj       32.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sdf        1.59TiB
   /dev/sdg        1.73TiB
   /dev/sdh        5.52TiB
   /dev/sdi        1.26TiB
   /dev/sdj        9.09TiB
```

Notice the entries for `Data,RAID1` and `Metadata,RAID1` don't include the new disk, `/dev/sdj`.

### Troubleshooting steps

Shooting in the dark, I tried:

`sudo btrfs filesystem resize max /mnt/btrfs/ba07`

and

`sudo btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /mnt/btrfs/ba07`

The results are the same, the disk is not being listed under `Data,RAID1` or `Metadata,RAID1`.

More recently I tried the tips from the comment from EarthMind below, combined with [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/337497/306914) recommendation:

```
btrfs device delete /dev/sdj /mnt/btrfs/ba07              #Succeeded
btrfs device add    /dev/sdj /mnt/btrfs/ba07              #Succeeded
btrfs balance start -mconvert=raid1,soft /mnt/btrfs/ba07  #Tip said to do these balances separately, metadata first
btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1,soft /mnt/btrfs/ba07
```

All steps finished immediately, and with nothing being done in the background; presumably this was because I had already run variations on balancing numerous times already, and also there was no data to on sdj to move before removing.

`sudo btrfs fi usage` showed the same thing: /dev/sdj not part of Data or Metadata RAID1.

Since the definition of insanity is popularly defined as doing the same thing over and over expecting different results, I'm currently doing just that:

```
sudo btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /mnt/btrfs/ba07
```

For whatever reason, *that* seems to actually be doing something. (But not when done individually, and even though I've tried the exact same command several times earlier.) Specifically, /dev/sdj appears to be undergoing writes, which is the whole goal here. It's too early to claim victory, as this could take many hours to days to finish. Specifically, this part of the output from `btrfs fi usage /mnt/btrfs/ba07` seems promising:

```
Data,RAID1: Size:8.40TiB, Used:8.36TiB
   /dev/sdf        5.56TiB
   /dev/sdg        5.45TiB
   /dev/sdh        3.47TiB
   /dev/sdi        2.31TiB
   /dev/sdj       19.00GiB
```

The last line, /dev/sdj, is growing.

### Additional info

System info:

```
$ btrfs --version
btrfs-progs v4.15.1

$ uname -r
4.15.0-54-generic

$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
```

### Similar problems on the web

- [btrfs raid1 not using all disks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358770/btrfs-raid1-not-using-all-disks)

  - Was behaving as expected. Since existing drives had more free space, they were being written to before the new disk. My situation is the opposite, new drive has more free space.
- [Btrfs adding smaller drive to RAID1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281255/btrfs-adding-smaller-drive-to-raid1)

  - User wound up having to take a different approach altogether when a disk wound up dying.
- [Why does btrfs refuse to convert metadata to RAID1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199935/why-does-btrfs-refuse-to-convert-metadata-to-raid1?rq=1)

  - Was due to a regression in the specific Btrfs version (4.0). But I tried these steps on both 4.4, and 4.15.
- [BTRFS balance completed, but still shows data stored in “single” mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336909/btrfs-balance-completed-but-still-shows-data-stored-in-single-mode?rq=1)

  - Suggested adding "soft" parameter to convert filters, and running `-mconvert=raid1,soft` separately before `-dconvert=raid1,soft`. This solution didn't solve my problem.

### Summary

<s>Clearly I must be doing something wrong, but hours of googling and experimenting have so far yielded nothing, other than "it was done correctly and 'should' work".</s>

It tentatively seems to be working with `sudo btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /mnt/btrfs/ba07`, after having removed and re-added the disk from the array, even though that's the third or fourth try with the same command. I'll add this as an answer in a few hours or days, whenever it finishes:

```
#Repeat the third command below a few times if the whole thing doesn't work the first time.
#Note, don't specify "soft" parameter.
#If it's still not working, try the whole 3-line series of commands below multiple times.
#Because, software.

btrfs device delete /dev/sdj /mnt/btrfs/ba07
btrfs device add    /dev/sdj /mnt/btrfs/ba07
sudo btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /mnt/btrfs/ba07
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the device from the raid group, adding it again and immediately performing `sudo btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /mnt/btrfs/ba07` instead of `sudo btrfs balance start /mnt/btrfs/ba07`? I think a balance by default doesn't including metadata and data necessarily

Comment: I did run `sudo btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /mnt/btrfs/ba07` (as noted later in the question), but did not try removing the device first. That's a good idea, I'll try it, thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you got it solved, but don't edit your initial post to add the solution. Create a new answer instead and mark it as the solution. That way more it's more helpful to others.

Comment: I intend to, when it finishes and I know it worked. But I don't yet know that it's the or a solution. For now I just wanted to note what _seems_ to be working so far, so that someone doesn't go down a rabbit hole solving it, as low as those adds are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out *how* to fix it in this particular case (but not *why* it was happening). Nor can I be sure it would have "fixed" similar issues noted toward the end of the question above.

Either way, this clearly seems to be undesired, unintended, or at best undocumented behavior on Btrfs' part. (For example, it may just be "undocumented" that you have to do these steps in order for Btrfs to start using a newly added device. As to why it doesn't always work...is another question.)

In this (real) example:

- `/dev/sdj` is the device to add, that btrfs isn't using to distribute data to.
- `/mnt/btrfs/ba07` is the mounted location for the array.

```
btrfs device delete /dev/sdj /mnt/btrfs/ba07
btrfs device add    /dev/sdj /mnt/btrfs/ba07
sudo btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /mnt/btrfs/ba07
```

Usual disclaimers, make sure your data is backed up. The `device delete` command is supposed to do so without data loss (and did), and should work as long as there's enough room on the other disks to receive the removed device's data (which is obviously the case if it's not even being used), but better safe than sorry.

If it didn't work, and assuming the rest of your array does have data and the newly added disk is empty, you'll notice after the `btrfs balance start`... that:

- The command (`btrfs balance start`...) probably returns right away,
- `btrfs balance status /mountpoint` shows no activity, and
- The `Data,RAID1` section of `btrfs fi usage` output, does not list the new device.

If it didn't work, try the last command (`btrfs balance start`...) again.

If that still doesn't work, try all three commands again.

I don't know if doing it multiple times is always required, or why it necessary in this case. (In my case, the last command by itself didn't work no matter how many times it was run. But after deleting and re-adding the device, *then* doing the balance command twice (with some elapsed time and random unrelated commands in between), it started working the second time.

Also note that in this particular case, these *didn't* work, even after multiple attempts:

- Performing the metadata balance separately, before the data balance (as was suggested in a similar question, documented in the question above).
- Adding the `,soft` parameter to the `-mconvert=raid1` and `-dconvert=raid1` arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I had noticed the same problem.  My initial RAID 1 pair is (2)12TB drives.  When I added more drives (2)8TB, I couldn't figure out why the new drives were not getting used according to **btrfs filesystem usage /path**.  I did more research and discovered the algorithm used by btrfs is add to the drive with the most free space.  So until the 12TB pair uses up 4TB, the 8TB pair will not get used.

My tests show that you only need to use the **btrfs device add /dev /path** command and do not need to run the **btrfs balance** command for btrfs RAID 1 to work.

I hope that future iterations of the RAID 1 btrfs filesystem use a percentage free space algorithm instead of an absolute free space.  This will become important when SSD disks are used for wear balancing.

For now I have come up with a band-aid.  I start my pool of disks by setting the filesystem size of each disk to that of the smallest disk in the pool.  Thereby forcing RAID 1 to use all disks in the pool equally.  When the pool becomes full I resize the remaining disks to the next smallest disk capacity so the remaining disks get used equally.
This also helps reduce the time for rebuilding should a disk fail since the data is more distributed.

You can mkfs.btrfs the whole partition on a disk, then set usable space of each drive in the pool with the **btrfs filesystem resize {devid}:{size} /path**
So if my samllest disk is 4TB I would **btrfs filesystem resize {1..4}:4T /path**.  The disk's devid is found with **btrfs filesystem show**.